# Assigning increment number to <li></li> value

Tags: php, for-loop

I am displaying list of category from MySQL database and while displaying those category I am trying to assign the value of each item from **2 to 9**. So when all `(8 row in total)` category displayed, the value should start from **2, 3, 4, 5 .... 9**.

Here is what I did in my coding :

```
$select_cat = "SELECT * FROM tblcat";
$result_cat = $conn->query($select_cat);
if ($result_cat->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row_disp_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cat))
    {
        for ($id = 2; $id <=9; $id++)
        {
            echo '<li><a id="'.$id.'">'.$row_disp_cat['catName'].'</a></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

With above code I am getting the value looping `8 times` of `2-9`

Comment: Is $conn an instance of PDO?

Comment: @AlexandruUngureanu it's mysqli

Comment: Is the $id meant to be coming from your tblcat ? e.g. the primary key of that?

Comment: @AlexandruUngureanu $id is a variable to hold the incrementing number of 2 to 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it help.

```
$select_cat = "SELECT * FROM tblcat";
$result_cat = $conn->query($select_cat);
if ($result_cat->num_rows > 0)
{
    $id = 2;
    while($row_disp_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_cat))
    {
        echo '<li><a id="'.$id.'">'.$row_disp_cat['catName'].'</a></li>';
        $id++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use PDO for reasons beyond the scope of this answer which you should investigate yourself for the fun of it. However, you should remove the for loop and use the Primary Key of your tblcat entries as the $id so you can  find them after your user has selected an option. If the $id has to have a value between 2 and 8 then you should use @Hossein's suggestion.